# Is there a term for "is mapped to by an isomorphism"?

Tags: terminology

In any context where isomorphisms are defined.

For example, if $G$ and $H$ are two isomorphic groups, then there exists an isomorphism mapping their identity elements together. That is to say, their identity elements are `_____`, where `_____` is the word I'm looking for.

Example two: a graph is vertex transitive if and only if its vertices are pairwise `_____`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $G$, $H$ are groups, there does *not* exist an isomorphism between them. 
However, maybe you are looking for the word *characteristic*.

A characteristic thingie is such that it is unchanged under automorphisms.
For example

- the identity element of a group,
- the center of a group,
- the set of elements of even order

are characteristic (elements, subgroups, subsets) of $G$.
On the other hand, e.g. $p$-Sylow groups are in general not characteristic (because there can be several, i.e. there is not "the" Sylow group).

---

A graph is vertex transitive if and only if its vertices are pairwise *in the orbit of one another under the operation of the automorphism group*(!?)
In a way, looking at the operation of the automorphism group on (elements, subgroups, ...) of $G$, characteristic (elements, subgroups, ...) are those having one-point orbits.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that they obviously need to be isomorphic groups.